# How can we predict the formula of a coordination compound by just knowing the ligand and central metal?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, coordination-compounds, transition-metals, ligand-field-theory

### Question:

> On complete reaction of $\ce{FeCl3}$ with oxalic acid in aqueous solution
> containing $\ce{KOH}$, resulted in the formation of product A. The secondary valency of $\ce{Fe}$ in the product A is:

Now my teacher told me that in this compound the secondary valency of iron would be 6, and told me to remember the formula of all the compounds in *GRB Organic Chem*.

I have a rough idea that six is the most common secondary valency, but beyond that I fail to see any trend.

Can someone help me out, so that I can predict the formula of such compounds without rote learning?

Only tetravalent and hexavalent compounds are in my course, I also know how to predict whether a compound would be high spin or low spin. My doubt is mainly about whether they will be hexavalent or tetravalent.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing to notice here would be the fact that you see an acid along side a base.

$$\ce{H2C2O4 + 2KOH -> K2C2O4.H2O + H2O}$$

Now, this reacts with the ferric chloride present in the solution to give potassium tris(oxalato)ferrate(III). Many if not all iron complexes are hexavalent in nature.

$$\ce{3K2C2O4.H2O(aq) + FeCl3.6H2O(aq) -> K3[Fe(C2O4)3].3H2O(aq) + 3KCl(aq)}$$

This is in fact how you would prepare the said complex as explained in [this lab manual](https://www.atilim.edu.tr/shares/chem/files/LAB/che%C3%B6106/CHEM%20106_EXP%206.pdf)

> Potassium trisoxalatoferrate(III) trihydrate, $\ce{K3[Fe(C2O4)3].3H2O}$ is a green crystalline salt, soluble in hot water but rather insoluble when cold. It can be prepared by the reaction of $\ce{K2C2O4.H2O}$ with $\ce{FeCl3.6H2O}$

Comment: Is there any such rule for elements other than iron?

Comment: @SunainaDas, in inorganic chemistry there is no fixed rule for all sets of compounds. Instead of worrying about rote learning, just focus on seeing the different patterns. This is a similar such pattern.